# PHP - How to find the highest date on multidimensional array indexing by another array value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I have an array similar to this and now I need to check all the records and create a new array containing the name of users and their latest "Updated" date.
What is the best way to do this in PHP?

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [user] => User1
        [Updated] => 2016-11-07T10:43:14.000+0100
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [user] => User2
        [Total] => 2016-12-08T10:43:14.000+0100
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [user] => User1
        [Total] => 2015-11-07T10:43:14.000+0100
    )
```

)

Any help is welcome!
Thanks!

Comment: Create a new array, loop through array above, if sub arrays have updated key, add user and updated time to the new array?  Or filter out all members without the updated key.  It might help to list an example of your desired output as well as input, and give examples of what you've tried so far.